# Java two's complement binary to integer

Tags: java, binary, twos-complement

I know that converting a decimal to binary with `Integer.toBinaryString(355)  = 0000000101100011` and 
                                           `Integer.toBinaryString(-355) = 1111111010011101` (where I take the lower 16 bits of the 32 bit result).

What I would like to do is the other way and take a 16-bit twos's complement binary string and to convert to decimal.

i.e.

```
0000000000110010 =  50
1111111111001110 = -50
```

Rather than `1111111111001110 = 65486`

How would I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to read the result into `short`.

```
short res = (short)Integer.parseInt("1111111111001110", 2);
System.out.println(res);
```

This [prints `-50`](http://ideone.com/RQJ92F).

Answer (score 2):

Use a `short`? They occupy 16 bits.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html