# Integer.parseInt(x, 2) is not considering sign bit

Tags: java, parseint

When doing `Integer.parseInt(x, 2)`, it's not considering the sign bit.

Take this example,

```
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(-1)); // This output's "11111111111111111111111111111111"
System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(Integer.toBinaryString(-1), 2));
```

The second line throws,

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "11111111111111111111111111111111"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at com.Test.main(Test.java:116)
```

I have a scenario to convert `Integer` to `Binary String` and then convert it back.

Is there a way to let the `parseInt()` method parse it **with** the sign bit?

### EDIT:

The answer's in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15837899/java-twos-complement-binary-to-integer) question have a hacky solution to use `parseXX()` method on a larger datatype (eg: Integer.parseInt() while needing short, or Long while needing int). This wont work if someone is trying to parse a negative long (since there's no larger type than long).

But @Tagir's answer seems to work for all Types. So leaving this question open.

Comment: "This wont work in all cases" ... can you give an example of a case where it won't work?

Comment: Your question was about `int` or `Integer` types, so it was far from clear that "all cases" was referring to larger types.  And it certainly _does_ work in "all cases" that are covered by your parenthesized phrase.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since Java 8 you can use [`Integer.parseUnsignedInt(s, 2);`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseUnsignedInt-java.lang.String-int-):

```
System.out.println(Integer.parseUnsignedInt(Integer.toBinaryString(-1), 2));
```

Comment: This is working great. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Try using

```
int i = Long.valueOf(str, 2).intValue();
```

Using:

```
int i = Long.valueOf("11111111111111111111111111111111", 2).intValue();
System.out.print(i);
```

Output:

```
-1
```

Comment: @ILikeTau Try running it yourself.

Comment: Hmm…I didn't see the `intValue().` Reupvoting and deleting my comment.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Integer API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html), `Integer.toBinaryString()` returns the twos complement, not the signed version. This is why this throws a `NumberFormatException`.
You can use `Integer.parseUnsignedInt()` instead.

Comment: Ya. But is there a way to parse it back properly without the exception?

Comment: Use `Integer.parseUnsignedInt()`.

Answer (score 0):

"11111111111111111111111111111111" too long

```
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(-1)); 
// This output's "11111111111111111111111111111111"
System.out.println(Long.parseLong(Integer.toBinaryString(-1), 2));
```

Comment: This doesn't work, since it returns the *twos complement*, which is not fixed by using a `Long`.

Comment: @ILikeTau Casting the resulting `long` to `int` should work, though.

Comment: Yes, but the answer didn't say that. Also, using `Integer`'s methods when working on them seems more elegant.